# Calculating Total count from different SELECTs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following code in my Stored Procedure written in SQL Server 2008:

```
    select sum(Sum1)
    from
    (
        select count(1) as Sum1 from Table1
        UNION ALL 
        select count(1) as Sum1 from Table2
        UNION ALL 
        select count(1) as Sum1 from Table3
        UNION ALL 
        select count(1) as Sum1 from Table4

    ) as SumCount
```

There are more SELECT statements joined by UNION ALL. How I can rewrite the query to optimize performance? Does any other operator instead of UNION ALL will help to improve performance?

Comment: Not scanning every table from end to end would improve performance. Have you looked at views like `sys.partitions`? There's a `rows` column that has this information - relatively up to date - which will be much more efficient than this scan of every table in the database...

Comment: I would go with @AaronBertrand's suggestion. Here is a good example of it: http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/count-the-number-of-rows-in-every-table-in-a-database-in-no-time/

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: You should post answers as answers not as comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is about as fast as it gets. You want to count all rows from all tables and this is what you are doing. (To use `COUNT(*)` would be more clear, though, as you want to count rows. Using `COUNT(1)` means count all rows for which a generated 1 is not null, but of course the dbms optimizes this to `COUNT(*)` internally.)

You can also try:

```
select
  (select count(*) from Table1) +
  (select count(*) from Table2) +
  (select count(*) from Table3) +
  (select count(*) from Table4);
```

which is even more readable I think. I suppose that the dbms will use the same execution plan though. Well, you can still try.

Comment: `COUNT(<any constant>)` can't possibly return `NULL` for any row. I think you are mixing this up with `COUNT(<any nullable column>)`. In any case, can you explain why this is as fast as it gets, when a non-blocking query against a DMV will not only avoid any actual table scans, it also won't block (or be blocked)? While the DMV data is arguably not 100% accurate, neither is a blocking `COUNT(*)` because as soon as it is finished, all those operations that were blocked will get their turn, and render the count immediately obsolete and inaccurate.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I simply describe what count(something) means: test that something for null; if it is not null then count it. Of course the dbms notices that 1 can never be null and simply does a count(\*), i.e. count rows. It is optimizing. As to as fast as it can get: If you want to count records and you want to know if it's 50 or 60 records, the only way I know of is use COUNT. I know that SQL Server has some statistics and knows a table's approximate row count, but this is just an estimate. Enough for the optimizer to build an execution plan, but still just an approximate value.

Comment: The DMVs are pretty accurate - this isn't strictly about cardinality. Anyway if your goal is accuracy over speed, then you shouldn't sell your solution on speed when you know that isn't true (and you should also acknowledge that even a very expensive count can only be accurate for so long).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Okay, point taken. I've just never seen the case when one wanted just an approximite value from the dbms. But well, I've never seen the case when someone wanted to add row counts of different tables either ;-) So maybe the result doesn't have to be precise. And yes, there are tables that change very often, and if that's the case for the mentioned tables, then the count is just precise for the moment taken.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is how I would do it, because it allows the optimizer to use data in the catalog to produce the answer, rather than table/index I/O.

There is another way to do this that I have never tried, but it might be worth a shot:

```
select count(*) from
(
    select 1 a from Table1
    UNION ALL 
    select 1 from Table2
    UNION ALL 
    select 1 from Table3
    UNION ALL 
    select 1 from Table4
) as SumCount
```

Let me know how it compares with your query.